# Can you setup absolute paths in a serverless application

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a serverless app where I have a bunch of folders like models, handlers, libs, etc. The directory structure looks like this:

```
handlers
libs
models
node_modules
package.json
serverless.yml
```

I like to structure my serverless methods so that it's nested for the paths but it becomes very deep pretty fast. For example it may look something like this:

```
handlers
  user
    auth
      login
        post.js
    read.js
    update.js
    delete.js
```

This means that in the user/auth/login/post handler I may have to import something models and the import is gonna look like

```
const User = require("../../../../models/User")
```

What I would prefere to do is something like

```
const User = require("models/User")
```

But I haven't found any solutions to achieve this in serverless framework yet